# Signal strength is much lower on 5GHz

Tags: wireless-networking

So I have a PC connected to my router thru a Cisco Wireless ac USB Adapter, the thing I found funny is when I am connected to the router thru 2.4GHz network, my signal strength is ~-68db which is great according to [this link](https://support.metageek.com/hc/en-us/articles/201955754-Understanding-WiFi-Signal-Strength). But when I switch to 5GHz network the signal strength drops to ~-80db which is unusable at all.

Regarding the router location its only about 5 metres away, although separated by a wall.

Comment: Walls are a killer for 5 GHz WiFi, especially those with metal in them. However, you can still try putting a (short!) USB extension between your PC and the adapter, to minimize interference coming from the PC.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [Linksys page:](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=134478)

> Range
>
> The 5 GHz band has a shorter range compared to a 2.4 GHz band because
>   in radio frequencies, the higher the frequency the shorter its range. 
>   In other words, if you are using a lower frequency like the 2.4 GHz,
>   the distance it will cover will be greater than the 5 GHz band.

So, with 5GHz you'll get lower interference from other devices, more speed, but shorter range.

If you want to move farter from the router, the 2.4GHz will give you that range, but get more interference.

Comment: Everyday physics: Higher frequencies always require more energy, so a common antenna in a Wireless device will give a shorter range (assuming the manufacturers won't improve the power transmission noticeably).